# Capture event within app: shell toast pops-up

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to capture this event in an app?
The application is not the caller of the Show method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't capture a toast being shown. 
You only can register to receive an event when a toast notification (push notification) is received for your application, registering to the event:

`ShellToastNotificationReceived`

You can take a look at this [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202967%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: I mean a local toast.